# I've tried everything but I'm still having trouble installing Laravel on Mac

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've updated the composer, and when I follow the steps to download Laravel, I can't go past the first step because I get this failed error message. I've searched GitHub and Stack Overflow and tried everything, but nothing works.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/tinker ^2.8, found laravel/tinker[2.x-dev] but it does not match your minimum-stability.
>
> Problem 2
> - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^10.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[10.0.0, ..., 10.0.11].
> - phpunit/phpunit[10.0.0, ..., 10.0.11] require phpunit/php-code-coverage ^10.0 -> found
> phpunit/php-code-coverage[dev-main, 10.0.x-dev (alias of dev-main)],
> but it does not match your minimum stability.
>
> Problem 3
> - laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.0.2] require doctrine/inflector ^2.0.5 -> found doctrine/inflector[2.0.x-dev,
> 2.1.x-dev] but it does not match your minimum-stability.
>
> Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.2].

`php --version` is v8.2.3, Composer version 2.5.4, mySQL  Ver 8.0.32

> ```
>  composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app = failed
> ```

**composer.json**

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/,"
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Did you add a `composer.json` yourself? If so, can we see it? (The Composer error mentions one, but I wonder if that is auto-generated).

Comment: @halfer No I didn't add a composer.json myself. It was auto-generated. I should also mention that when I try to create a new project, I get the error but the 'new project' is also partially created and that's where the composer.json file exists.

Comment: "when I follow the steps to download Laravel," - what does that mean? If you are facing problems when running the exact commands given by anybody else, you should ask whoever gave you these instructions for clarification

Comment: I should think that Laravel would be very good at keeping up with PHP versions, but I did wonder if PHP 8.2 was too new. Can you easily try PHP 8.1 on your system?

Comment: Ah, I bet `composer/composer` is on v10.0.2, which was released [4 days ago as of today](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tags). Try an earlier version e.g. `composer create-project laravel/laravel:9.5.2 example-app`. I expect you can delete your existing `example-app` as it is all auto-generated (until you commit the skeleton and make changes).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. I finally worked it out.

Comment: I deleted all composer files from the directory, including composer installer. I reinstalled it globally following the instructions from https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-composer