# Problems displayed while creating a new project of Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a new project of Laravel 10. I have Composer version is **2.5.4** and PHP version is **8.1.12**. All requirements are correct according to creating laravel 10 version but its displayed me these problems

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**

- Root composer.json requires laravel/tinker ^2.8, found laravel/tinker[2.x-dev] but it does not match your minimum-stability.

**Problem 2**

- Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^10.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[10.0.0, ..., 10.0.11].
- phpunit/phpunit[10.0.0, ..., 10.0.11] require phpunit/php-code-coverage ^10.0 -> found phpunit/php-code-coverage[dev-main, 10.0.x-dev (alias of dev-main)] but it does not match your minimum-stability.

**Problem 3**

- laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.0.2] require doctrine/inflector ^2.0.5 -> found doctrine/inflector[2.0.x-dev, 2.1.x-dev] but it does not match your minimum-stability.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.2].

Comment: How did you install the project?

Comment: @brombeer
using this command
"composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app"

Comment: Same issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75514807/ive-tried-everything-but-im-still-having-trouble-installing-laravel-on-mac

Comment: @Charlie
I have fixed this issue by uninstall composer and install again composer.